# Loading a large(>100MB) text file into iframe gives OutofMemory exception

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

My filepath has log files of different sizes. The below method works for files smaller than 100MB, anything over that gets an OutofMemory exception.

```
var stream = System.IO.File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open, 
                      FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);
 return File(stream, "text/plain");
```

and loading the above file to iframe which gets me to the problem of OutOfMemory

```
<iframe loading="lazy" src="@Url.Action("ActionName", "Admin", new {FileName = "test"})" ></iframe>
```

Is there a way to reduce the memory usage here? I have tried using StreamReader, BufferedStream, StreamWriter etc. Nothing seems to be working. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Maybe re-tag this. You don't need to escape quotation marks in `src` there? Crazy stuff.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a reazor page. The quotes should work fine (just tested in .net 6).

Comment: Yes, it is a Razor page, the problem is nothing wrt src, the problem is with the large file loading into it,  just mentioned it to show what I am trying to do

Comment: I'm kinda confused as to why you are using an iframe to display a file. Is there any need for the file to be over 100mb and or would it be possible to have the file on a disk where people are redirected to a page where they can view/download the file

Comment: The Files to be displayed are log files which are stored in the disk whose size can vary from 4MB to 4GB. I am redirecting to specific log file depending on the user selection and iframe is necessary as it formats the log files readable without much confusion

Comment: Couldn't you let the person download the log? I personally dislike reading files through a page. Isn't it more logical to setup a good authorisation around the download page.

Comment: some of the log files are and user don't need to download them, also for security reasons too